# Crashing whenever any buttons are clicked

Tags: java, android

The app executed just fine, and the interface loads just fine as well, but when I try to press any of the buttons, nothing that should happen happens. The point is fairly simple: press the '+' button, the quantity increases, and the price immediately updates to match said quantity, vice versa for the '-' button. I don't know what I've done wrong, but any button interaction with the app crashes it.

Here's my Java:

```
package com.t99sdevelopment.mobile.eyy;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public int quantityValue = 1;

public void increaseQuantity (View view) {
    quantityValue = quantityValue + 1;
    updateQuantityValue(view);
}

public void decreaseQuantity (View view) {
    quantityValue = quantityValue - 1;
    updateQuantityValue(view);
}

public void updateQuantityValue(View view) {
    updateQuantity(quantityValue);
    updatePrice(quantityValue);
}

private void updateQuantity(int number) {
    TextView quantity = (TextView) findViewById(
            R.id.quantityValue);
    quantity.setText(number);
}

private void updatePrice(int number) {
    TextView price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.priceValue);
    price.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(number * 5));
    }
}
```

Here's my XML:

```
<TextView
    android:text="Quantity"
    android:id="@+id/quantityText"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:autoText="false"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:text="0"
        android:id="@+id/quantityValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="-"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/quantityValue"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/quantityValue"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:onClick="decreaseQuantity" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="+"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/quantityValue"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/quantityValue"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:onClick="increaseQuantity" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:text="Price"
    android:id="@+id/priceText"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:autoText="false"
    android:paddingTop="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="$0"
    android:id="@+id/priceValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp" />

<Button
    android:text="Order"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The formatting of the actual code is just fine, but it got screwy when I pasted in into stack, so I know that's not the problem.

Comment: Show the error from the log please.

Comment: Add your onClick method and updatePrice method too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you `updateQuantity` and `updatePrice` method like :

```
private void updateQuantity(int number) {
    TextView quantity = (TextView) findViewById(
            R.id.quantityValue);
    quantity.setText(String.valueOf(number));
}

private void updatePrice(int number) {
    TextView price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.priceValue);
    price.setText(String.valueOf(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(number * 5)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I for some reason didn't realize when that I was setting a string field to an int.